# CSS HTML why do things resize based on screen width when I specify width in px?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, pixel, text-size

How come text resizes proportionally when the screen resizes even though I set the font size in px instead of em or % or something like that? I'm pretty sure the pixels on my monitor don't change size...

When I set the px value to look normal on a wide screen it ends up way too small on small screens like cellphones. I want to be able to use something like `@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)` to specify what the text should be on small screens instead of it shrinking on its own.

I made a very simple page to make sure nothing I did earlier messes with it. I have the text sized to be readable on a regular pc screen:

[image]

But if I resize the screen to less then 1000px width the text shrinks without me specifying the new text size or using em or % values.

[image]

The text should fill like half the empty space.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">
<div>
    <div class="t_banner">Banner</div>
    <div class="t_banner2">Banner sub text</div>
</div>
<div><span>Phone</span> <span>999-999-9999</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{margin: 0;}

.banner{background-color: #f0eedb; height: 185px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px #555;}

.t_banner{color: #413e3e; font-size: 50px; font-weight: 600; font-family: Roboto Condensed, serif; border-bottom: solid 3px #222;}
.t_banner2{color: #413e3e; font-size: 45px; font-weight: 500; font-style: italic; font-family: Roboto Condensed, serif;}
```

**EDIT:**
I experimented by removing the height: 185px; from the .banner styles. Then I added some more text to the banner:

[image]

I also added a

with no styles between the  and the . The banner text is still resizes, but the the phone and

"text" at the bottom doesn't.

Now if I either remove the extra "banner sub text" or bring back "height 185px" then everything, including the completely unrelated p text ends up tiny. Everything seems completely random at this point, and I only have like 2 files with a few lines each

Comment: Notes: Do you really escape the quotes in the charset? Also, the `<link>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: Using your code, the text doesn't resize. Sure you posted all of your CSS?

Comment: Inspect your page and check in the Styles section where the `font-size` is coming from.

Comment: It shows up as 45px or w/e I put in my css as normal. It's not crossed out as if something is overriding the font-size and changing the value affects the size, but it still looks like different sizes on small screen vs wide. It's like the resolution changes as the div size changes.

Comment: @Daniel Sixl ya that's everything. I made a new directory so I can test it in a void where I know there is no chance of old files or styles affecting it that I don't know about. Unless it's possible that some server setting is affecting it? I wasn't the first to work on this server, but I removed all the old stuff that were in public_html

Comment: I guess we need to see it  on your server then. Can you make it public?

Comment: I tried it on another server that normally works, but it still does the same thing. So it can't be from the server

Answer (score 1):

I think what is throwing you off is that you don't have a viewport meta tag in the head of your document, and without this, by default mobile devices will typically scale the page to fit the screen.

Scaling the page usually includes scaling the images, and as you have seen, scaling the font sizes.

To verify this check this codepen: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/MERRxy

If you visit the live view at https://s.codepen.io/panchroma/debug/MERRxy/wQAPoZQNRWer on any device I think you will find that the fonts are full size and isn't shrinking.

The HTML and CSS for this example are exactly the same as you have posted above, except that I added a viewport meta tag in the head of the page. You'll see that if you comment out this tag, font sizes will shrink in the live view.

More about viewport meta tags:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Hope this helps!

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" /> -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">
<div>
    <div class="t_banner">Banner</div>
    <div class="t_banner2">Banner sub text</div>
</div>
<div><span>Phone</span> <span>999-999-9999</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{margin: 0;}

.banner{background-color: #f0eedb; height: 185px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px #555;}

.t_banner{color: #413e3e; font-size: 50px; font-weight: 600; font-family: Roboto Condensed, serif; border-bottom: solid 3px #222;}
.t_banner2{color: #413e3e; font-size: 45px; font-weight: 500; font-style: italic; font-family: Roboto Condensed, serif;}
```